# Web technologies exam query

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I have a practical exam in web technologies so html, css, javascript and (possibly) php. I'm still learning and just wondered if you guys had any advice. HTML im fine with, css sometimes takes me time to get right and javascript and php get a bit messy! It's open book, so what would you suggest taking with me?

Answer (score 4):

An iPhone (plus some words to make this pithy response longer...)

Answer (score 0):

If you want (or can take books with you), look for books with good indexes, so you can find the stuff you as fast as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Bring S.O.?

That would be awesome if S.O had an options to print (or download) your selected "interesting tags" and stared questions like it was a book. AND it should include a index. (Obviously it should be filtered somehow so you don't get 10000 pages)

Comment: I'm sorry, not to sound completely ignorant, but im still quite new to this stuff, what is s.o?